# What is the earliest mention of an estimate of 71% water (or 70.8%) / 29% land (or 29.2%)?

Tags: 20th-century, 19th-century, maps, geography

According to the U.S. Geological Survey's article *[How much water is there on, in, and above the Earth?](https://water.usgs.gov/edu/earthhowmuch.html)*,

> About 71 percent of the Earth's surface is water-covered

Wikipedia's [Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth) article also gives ‘about’ 71% (with 29% land) and also cites the perhaps more precise figures of 70.8% / 29.2% found on [this University of British Columbia Okanagan page](http://www.physicalgeography.net/fundamentals/8o.html), but none of these sources say ***when*** these estimates were first made.

The only estimate with a date I’ve found is in [*A comprehensive atlas, geographical, historical & commercial [cartographic material]*](https://archive.org/details/comprehensiveatl00brad/page/9), published in 1835, which states that oceans (including inland bays and seas) cover

> about three fourths of the surface of the globe.

However, this source does not include Antarctica, the last continent to be discovered, which [accounts for 9.2% of earth's land area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continent), and around 2.6% of the earth’s surface.

Antarctica was discovered in the early 1820s, but it was not until in the [late 1830s / early 1840s that three expeditions sailed around the continent](https://www.coolantarctica.com/Antarctica%20fact%20file/History/exploration-history.php). Not until several decades later, [from the late 1890s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroic_Age_of_Antarctic_Exploration), were there many expeditions to Antarctica. The map below, dated 1906, appears to be one of the earliest Antarctica maps in which the continent’s shape is reasonably recognizable (there is also what appears to be a less accurate [one from 1897](https://www.pinterest.ph/pin/189432728057387928/)).

[image]

*Antarctica 1906 map. Source: [A Brief History of Antarctica](https://www.duraglobes.com/blog/maps-of-antarctica/)*

**What is the earliest mention of an estimate of 71% water (or 70.8%) / 29% land (or 29.2%)?** *(an answer for either will be acceptable)*

---

*Note on the comments below*

*While useful and informative, the comments unfortunately do not provide a date and focus more on the ‘how’ than the ‘when’. I am not asking ‘how’ (that would almost certainly be off-topic) but about ‘when’. Further, none of the sources cited (USGS, Wkipedia, University of British Columbia Okanagan) mention tides, seasonal cycles or the fractal nature of coastlines as affecting the percentages they cite, nor have I found any sources which give me reason to question the existing narrative (‘about 71% / 29%’ or 70.8% / 29.2%).*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) or even [Earth Science Stack Exchange](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Please demonstrate that the claim "*are widely cited on the internet*" can be verified as having an appropriate error estimate consistent with the implied precision of plus/minus 0.1%. It is not at all clear to me that these measurements are statically true throughout both the seasonal and tidal cycles of the year at that implied precision.

Comment: It was revised with the discovery and mapping of every new continent, until all continents were mapped and discovered and we arrived to these modern numbers. The last continent discovered was Antarctida, and it already took some time after that to find out that there is no land under the North Polar Ocean.

Comment: That's a telling edit - even the U.S. Geophysical Survey won't commit to the 71% being fully accurate in the units place. Therefore the error estimate is plus-or-minus > 1%, which is a good chunk of the 2.6% or so that comprises Antarctica. The problem with all these estimates is that the values can vary greatly depending on the scale of the map  used to calculate them - due to the fractal nature of coastlines.

Comment: This question was put on hold because it was deemed off-topic (3 or 4 votes).  While this question may fit on another site, this does not make it off-topic here as there is an overlap between many sites on SE. Further, many questions on this site which are tagged science, mathematics or geography require a greater knowledge of those subjects than they do of history, yet they have not been deemed off-topic. The remaining vote, or 2 votes, said this question is too basic. This is clearly not the case. Despite extensive research, I have not found a single link to an answer.

Comment: If you continue to work on this, Maury's "Physical Geography" of 1894 gives fractions of roughly 73-27.

Comment: I learned in 3rd grade it was 3/4 water.

Comment: @AaronBrick Thanks for that - interesting percentages given the date. I'll look in the Internet Archive for that.

Comment: @axsvl77 You have a better memory than me, I really can't remember what I was taught :)

Comment: There is the question of what counts as land. The north pole has permanent ice pack, and Antarctica has permanent ice shelves.

Comment: @BenCrowell Looking at the Wiki articles on [Land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land) and [Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth), ice doesn't count. Also, historically there was for a long time the question as to whether there was land under the North Pole ice cap.

Comment: @Alex: re "*The last continent discovered was Antarctida, and it already took some time after that to find out that there is no land under the North Polar Ocean.*" That is completely false. Dutch ships were sailing north of the 89th latitude in the early 1700's, plus the complete absence of icebergs north of the Greenland calving areas prove no land further north of that. So it was well known in the 18th century that there was no significant land masses in the arctic besides Greenland and the Canadian Arctic Archipelago.

Comment: @LarsBosteen: Likewise - see above. Presence/absence of icebergs is definitive, and has been well known as such for centuries. Plus there are the shipping logs of explorers from the turn of the 18th century sailing far north of the Arctic Circle, at time north of the 89th latitude.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Are you saying the Arctic Ocean was free of pack ice in the 1700s? A reference for that would be helpful.

Comment: @Spencer: **Correction above**: "*... north of 79th latitude*". [Farthest North](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farthest_North): "*A Dutch expedition led by Willem Barentz, attempting the Northeast Passage reached 79° 49’N on 16 June 1596, on the NW coast of Spitsbergen. ... English whalers reached Svalbard's Nordkapp at 80° 32′N, in or before 1622, as shown on the Muscovy Company's Map of 1625 The Seven Islands, at 80° 49′N, north of Nordaustlandet, were first marked on a Dutch map of 1663, but were allegedly reached by a ship of Enkhuizen as early as 1618.*"

Comment: @Spencer: [Northeast passage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northeast_Passage#11th_to_17th_centuries): "*By the 17th century, traders had established a continuous sea route from Arkhangelsk to the Yamal Peninsula, where they portaged to the Gulf of Ob. This route, known as the Mangazeya seaway, after its eastern terminus, the trade depot of Mangazeya, was an early precursor to the Northern Sea Route. ... East of the Taimyr, from the 1630s, Russians began to sail the Arctic coast from the mouth of the Lena River to a point beyond the mouth of the Kolyma River. ...*"

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I'd thought that might be a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at lots of atlases and physical geography books on the internet archive, the first mention I found of 70.8% water and 29.2% land is in the German [Knaurs WELT-ATLAS](https://archive.org/details/knaurs_weltatlas_1932/page/n17/mode/2up), 1932 edition.

Even more precise numbers are given by the book [Mother Earth by T. A. Ryder](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.104584/page/n17/mode/2up) in 1930 (so published two years earlier). It says 70.78% water and 29.22% land.

Most books between 1924 and 1932 don't give an exact number, they just say something like 'nearly or almost three fourths of the earth's surface is covered in water'.

It looks like some authors were behind current knowledge (or maybe the editions weren't updated?). For example, one book after 1930 says 72.5% water and 27.5% land ([Earth Lore A Physical Geography](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.123101/page/n67/mode/2up), 1932).

I haven't found anything close to your numbers before 1930, but the 1924 edition of Bartholomew's [The handy reference atlas of the world](https://archive.org/details/handyreferenceatlas1924/page/n7/mode/2up) gives areas which work out at 71.8% water and 28.2% land.